# Download Arrow Assist - Download a file, and have an arrow point where it is

Tags: html, css, download

This is my first post on Stackoverflow.

I have been wanting to add this to my website badly.

Im a certified computer technician, and have made a website completely out of scratch using Dreamweaver, however I still have much to learn.

Im trying to add a feature that www.MediaFire.com has when downloading a file. The process goes, you click the download button, and a big green arrow points to where the file is being downloaded (For the computer illiterate :p)

I looked at the Source on Media Fire and this is all I can find

```
<div id="arrow-chrome" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="arrow-ie" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="arrow-safari-mac" style="display:none"></div>
```

It appears as if all the goodies are in the stylesheet.

Does anyone know how I could get started setting this up on my website?

Here is a random link from MediaFire to show an example "http://www.mediafire.com/?q3bn6tdbabwkql7" Just click the download button and you will see that green arrow. (Works for IE and Chrome)

Thanks so much in advance :)

Brandon Berner

Comment: It's just a piece of Javascript that sniffs the browser and then displays an arrow depending on which browser it is. There's nothing magical that makes it point in the *actual* direction of "the download".

Comment: Here is a start: [http://jsfiddle.net/hY2Ce/](http://jsfiddle.net/hY2Ce/)

Comment: Thank you so much Sergio. Ill get started on this now! Sorry for such an easy question Deceze.

Comment: Ok So I have added it to my page. It shows continuously not only when you click the link. Nor does it check to see if the user is using chrome, or IE. Would it be missing js?
http://jsfiddle.net/at9Jy/

Comment: Easy questions are ok, I'm just demystifying the topic for you.

Comment: They use jQuery to animate that arrow. Here is the updated fiddle, similar to the one they currently have on mediafire: http://jsfiddle.net/hY2Ce/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/hY2Ce/4/show  (Firefox has fully customizable toolbar, so i guess that can be a reason, that the arrow is defined only for Chrome, IE9 and Safari-Mac.)

Comment: Or if you don't feel like learning the implications of jQuery, here's a simple javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/at9Jy/3 . Btw; love this part of your post: and have made a website completely out of scratch using Dreamweaver

Answer (score 10):

There is a JavaScript library on Github now that might solve your problem:
https://github.com/pbojinov/arrow-js